# How can I make back/forward history navigation not care about cursor position in VS Code interactive windows?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

When working with Python Interactive windows in VS Code, I find the following behaviour irritating:

When typing commands into the field at the bottom (where it says "Type 'python' code here and press Enter to run), these commands are added to some sort of history. Using Cursor-Up and Cursor-Down I can go back and forth through the commands I typed in a session. However, changing direction requires two key presses, because the first key press will bring the cursor only to the end or beginning of the line. This typically happens when searching for previously typed commands and whizzing past them with one too many presses of Cursor-Up, then having to press Cursor-Down *two times* to get to that command. Can this be changed?

Comment: you should generally only ask one question per question post. see [/help/dont-ask](/help/dont-ask). I've therefore removed your other two questions from this post. You can open the revision history and then copy those other questions into each their own new question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default binding for history navigation in interactive windows in VS Code are like this:

```json
{
  "key": "up",
  "command": "interactive.history.previous",
  "when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.interactive' && interactiveInputCursorAtBoundary != 'bottom' && interactiveInputCursorAtBoundary != 'none'"
},
{
  "key": "down",
  "command": "interactive.history.next",
  "when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.interactive' && interactiveInputCursorAtBoundary != 'none' && interactiveInputCursorAtBoundary != 'top'"
},
```

Note the parts of the when clause that use the `interactiveInputCursorAtBoundary` context key. If you want bindings that don't care about cursor position, just define copies of these bindings that exclude those parts of the when clause. I.e. put the following in your user keybindings.json file, which you can open by running `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette):

```json
{
  "key": "up",
  "command": "interactive.history.previous",
  "when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.interactive'"
},
{
  "key": "down",
  "command": "interactive.history.next",
  "when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.interactive'"
},
```